# GDB back trace from address

Tags: debugging, arm, gdb, embedded

I am experiencing an issue with GDB backtrace (bt).

When I hit the breakpoint I am in the interrupt context so debugging yields me information about intrerrupt stack only. Unfortunately this isn't very useful to debug my problem.

What I need instead, is a backtrace from the different address, one before we hit the interrupt function.  Fortunately in the embedded software I am working on, each time before the panic happens we leave a breadcrump preserving information about stack before the interupt.

My question is: Can I instruct GD to do print the back trace from a known address, (with the assumption that no remapping is happening in the hardware).

I am using gdb 7.0 with olimex, I am debugging custom ARM based chip.

Comment: Which gdb version are you using? It should be able to print the entire stack trace above the interrupt handler. Anyway, have you tried directly overwriting the stack and instruction pointers back to what they were? (btw you didn't specify architecture)

Comment: I am using remote debugger not the local one and It is not capable of writing to custom hardware SP and PC registers ( I have tried doing this as well). Lets just assume the GDB is not capable of retrieving full stack but I know where it is. The version of my gdb is: GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.0.1-37.el5), sadly it is quite old and I am not able to change it... In terms of arch it is custom arm based chip.

Comment: I'm afraid i'm not very arm-savvy, better tag your question accordingly to get the right help (please also edit the related info into the question)

Comment: 1) `can I ask GDB about to do the back trace from my known address`. I  see from description of `bt` http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Backtrace.html#Backtrace that `bt` does not expect address as parameter. 2) `info frame` accepts address as parameter. Can you run `info frame ADDR` in order to get info about the current frame and the frame that called it?